# insert multiple lines in the middle of a file before a specific string using shell script

Tags: sed

I have a log.txt file.The content of the file as below:

**Content of the file as below:**

```
properties{
set properties()
}

buildPipeline()
defPipeline(){
execute()
}
```

Now I have to insert below line just before **buildPipeline()**:

```
def testbranch= 'feature'
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startswith(testbranch)){
properties([pipelinetriggers([cron('0 */2 * * 1-5')]),])
}
```

I tried below .But it is inserting the statements at the end of the file:

```
sed -i -e "$adef testbranch= 'feature'" log.txt
sed -i -e "$aif(env.BRANCH_NAME.startswith(testbranch)){" log.txt
sed -i -e "$aproperties([pipelinetriggers([cron('0 */2 * * 1-5')]),])" log.txt
sed -i -e "$a}" log.txt
```

**Expected output:**

```
properties{
set properties()
}
def testbranch= 'feature'
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startswith(testbranch)){
properties([pipelinetriggers([cron('0 */2 * * 1-5')]),])
}
buildPipeline()
defPipeline(){
execute()
}
```

Comment: `$` means the last line, why are you using that if you don't want it to add at the end?

Comment: Modifying your code with `sed` is hard and brittle. Change the code so that it takes different branches depending on a configuration setting or command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` command should do the job:

```
sed -i "
/buildPipeline()/i\\
def testbranch= 'feature'\\
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startswith(testbranch)){\\
properties([pipelinetriggers([cron('0 */2 * * 1-5')]),])\\
}" log.txt
```

Note:  This is for GNU `sed`. BSD `sed` requires the extension for the backup file with `-i`

---

Edit after the comment by the OP, which requests that insertion must take place only on the first occurrence of `buildPipeline()`.

If you know the `buildPipeline()` won't occur on the first line of `log.txt`:

```
sed -i "
1,/buildPipeline()/!b
/buildPipeline()/i\\
def testbranch= 'feature'\\
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startswith(testbranch)){\\
properties([pipelinetriggers([cron('0 */2 * * 1-5')]),])\\
}" log.txt
```

Comment: Hi @M. Nejat Aydin, Thank you so much.The insertion is working.But i found that this buildPipeline() is getting repeated in the file multiple times and I want the insertion only before the 1st match.With above ,it is inserting before every match.How to restrict the entry only for the 1st match.Please help!!!Totally new to shell:-(

Comment: @rakshac Read the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

ed -s log.txt <<-'EOF'
/properties{/;/buildPipeline()/-,c
def testbranch= 'feature'
if(env.BRANCH_NAME.startswith(testbranch)){
properties([pipelinetriggers([cron('0 */2 * * 1-5')]),])
}
.
,p
Q
EOF
```

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is required.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output to `stdout`